# Is this a reasonable way to use C# dynamic?

Tags: c#, dynamic

Pardon the crude example. I have an encoder that returns an interface. Instead of using "is" and "as" to get the object that implements the interface, I would like to use dynamic to access a <strike>field</strike> property on the object. The <strike>field</strike> property is NOT on the interface, but is common across all objects that implement the interface.

EDIT: I should also mention that I do not have control of the encoder or it's interfaces so I can not modify them.

```
public class Program
{
  public Program()
  {
    dynamic temp = GetInterface();
    string s = temp.Blah;
    temp.Blah = s;
  }

  private ITest GetInterface()
  {
    return new Test();
  }
}
public interface ITest
{
}
public class Test : ITest
{
  public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If it's common across all objects, why is it not a part of the interface?

Comment: IMO the only reason to use `dynamic` is to interop with a language built on the DLR, like IronPython.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't modify the interface to include that member which is common to all the classes which implement it? `dynamic` seems like the wrong thing to use here (though yes, it works)

Comment: @RobertRouhani: Or for COM, or for lazy double-dispatch

Comment: @RobertRouhani - or a dynamic language not built on the DLR, such as interfacing with JavaScript in the host page from silverlight code. Or working with dynamic structured data e.g. parsed from XML or JSON.

Comment: Just a quick point on nomenclature. In the C# world, `Blah` would be called a property, not a field.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a very good example.  If all (or many) implementations of the interface have the field, then create an abstract implementation of the interface with the field, have the implementations derive from the abstract class instead of inherit the interface.  Then you can use the abstract class rather than the interface.

Answer (score 3):

The use will work just fine.  The `dynamic` binding will look through the type and find the underlying property.  From that perspective it's valid.

However if it's a property that's common to all implementations of the interface then why would you not just add it to the interface?  If it's a property you'd rather not make public then why not have a second internal interface which contains the property?

Comment: Of course, you can't add a field to an interface, but I still agree with you... make the field into a property and put it in the interface.

Comment: @DBM in this case though it is a property.  Updated my answer to use consistent terminology.

Comment: Valid, but not 'reasonable' as OP asks surely?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone it really depends. I hesitate to say the solution is not reasonable because the OP is using `dynamic` exactly as it was intended (for late bound access to members).  I would argue it's better to go the strongly typed approach but I'm a static guy.  A more dynamically minded person probably won't see any problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is acceptable and would compile. However, this feels like an anti pattern in my point of view. What happens when you rename the Blah property in the class one day? Sure it'll compile but...

Note: from your edit, I understand you can't add the property to ITest. So I would create a new interface "ITest2" with the property which Test implements, and let the compiler do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case you mentioned, it sounds like the property *should* be a member of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add `Blah` to `ITest`? That is:

```
public interface ITest
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```